# Не работает опция spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.from в application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Если указывать так, то работать почта будет:

```
 SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
 message.setFrom("no-reply@example.com");
```

А если указать через такие параметры, то работать не будет:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.from=no-reply@example.com
spring.mail.from.email=no-reply@example.com
spring.mail.from=no-reply@example.com
```

Как сделать, чтобы работало? Не хочется во всех местах кода указывать одинаковый `message.setFrom("no-reply@example.com");`

Ошибку такую выдает gmail, если использовать application.properties:

```
Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 not RFC 5322 compliant: 550-5.7.1 'From' header is missing. 550-5.7.1 To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been 550-5.7.1 blocked.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подразумевается, что Вы сами должны позаботиться о заполнении поля `SimpleMailMessage#from`. Список  доступных настройек Вы можете посмотреть в [документиции](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/boot-features-email.html#boot-features-email) или в [исходниках](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.1.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mail/MailProperties.java). В случае, если Вы хотите сделать кастомную настройку и использовать ее во всех необходимых местах, то воспользуйтесь аннотацией [Value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html). Примеры использования данной аннотации можете посмотреть [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation).

Comment: значит в инете обманывают по поводу тех настроек, которые я пробовал, они и не могли работать. благодарю за исчерпывающий ответ